# How to fix AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'theme_cls'

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying the Kivymd but keep getting the error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'theme_cls'.

I added the theme_cls = ThemeManager() in the App class but am still getting the error. Please help as there are no more solutions online.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition, WipeTransition

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivymd.navigationdrawer import MDNavigationDrawer
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager

class BeginScreen(Screen):
    pass

class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

Login = Builder.load_string('''
#: import Toolbar kivymd.toolbar.Toolbar


MyScreenManager:
    Screen:


<Screen>:

    Toolbar:
        title: "Simple toolbar"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.75}
        md_bg_color: get_color_from_hex(colors['Teal']['500'])
        background_palette: 'Teal'
        background_hue: '500'
    Toolbar:
        title: "Toolbar with right buttons"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
        md_bg_color: get_color_from_hex(colors['Amber']['700'])
        background_palette: 'Amber'
        background_hue: '700'
        right_action_items: [['content-copy', lambda x: None]]
    Toolbar:
        title: "Toolbar with left and right buttons"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.25}
        md_bg_color: get_color_from_hex(colors['DeepPurple']['A400'])
        background_palette: 'DeepPurple'
        background_hue: 'A400'
        left_action_items: [['arrow-left', lambda x: None]]
        right_action_items: [['lock', lambda x: None], \
            ['camera', lambda x: None], \
            ['play', lambda x: None]]


''')

class MyApp(App):
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()

    def build(self):
        return Login

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: What versions of python and kivymd are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Root Cause

When Kivy process the kv file / string, it instantiated the *root rule*, `MyScreenManager:` before the instantiation of `theme_cls`. When `MyScreenManager:` is instantiated, it instantiates its child, `Screen:`. When `Screen:` is instantiated, it instantiates its children, `Toolbar:` which references `theme_cls`. But `theme_cls` is not yet instantiated. Therefore, it threw the following error,

> ```
>  self._shadow = App.get_running_app().theme_cls.quad_shadow
> ```
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'theme_cls'

## Solution

### kv string

- Replace root rule, `MyScreenManager:` with class rule, `<MyScreenManager>:`

#### Snippets

```
Login = Builder.load_string('''
#:import Toolbar kivymd.toolbar.Toolbar


<MyScreenManager>:
    Screen:
```

### Python script

- Replace `return Login` with `return MyScreenManager()`

#### Snippets

```
class MyApp(App):
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()

    def build(self):
        return MyScreenManager()
```

## Output

[image: Result]

Comment: hi ikolim, I also realized my background in each screen turns white after adding theme_cls = ThemeManager() in the MyApp class. Any way to work around this? Would like to remain the same as before.

Comment: Use `app.theme_cls.theme_style = 'Dark'` to set background colour to black. The valid options are `Dark` or `Light`. The default is `Light`. You can change the theme style in `on_pre_enter` event.